# SendKeys is only putting end of input in text field

Tags: javascript, selenium

The script is running through a shipment creation form, locating xpaths, entering text from an excel sheet.

There is one field that keeps bugging out and while the script is writing the text it will be erased and only the tail end of the text is shown.
The following is an extract of the script:

```
driver // works
    .findElement(By.xpath(prop.getProperty("PostCodexpath")))
    .sendKeys(
        excel
            .getCell(53, i)
            .getContents()
    );

driver // works
    .findElement(By.xpath(prop.getProperty("Cityxpath")))
    .sendKeys(
        excel
            .getCell(51, i)
            .getContents()
    );

driver // fails
    .findElement(By.xpath(prop.getProperty("Statexpath")))
    .sendKeys(
        excel
            .getCell(52, i)
            .getContents()
    );
```

For the first two it works fine, finds the field and enters the text, but for the third line, I need the automation to find the xpath, pause for a second (no explicit pausing, nothing is being loaded), then enter the text.

*Background on the field:* It has an autosuggest feature which suggests a state based on the first 3 characters, but that is completely separate to the field and can be completely ignored. I am unable to replicate this by typing in the field or copy/pasting. It only happens when the automation is running.

Comment: Just check if the value passed from the excel is correct.

Comment: The binded event on this field  for autosuggest break the normal sendKeys(), you can use executeScript() to set value by javascript in client.  `driver.executeScript('arguments[0].value=arguments[1]', the field,  the value)`

Comment: `Autosuggestions` are part of the `HTML DOM`, you should treat them as a distinct `WebElement`

Answer (score 0):

You can try changing the input to char array and then input the same in the field char by char until you get an auto suggest and then selecting first value from auto-suggest values .

```
    char[] ar = excelvalue.toCharArray();

    String[] str = new String[ar.length];
    WebElement el = driver.findElementBy.Xpath(prop.getProperty("Statexpath")));
    for (int i = 0; i <= ar.length - 1; i++)

    {
        str[i] = String.valueOf(ar[i]);
        el.sendKeys(str[1]);
        Thread.sleep(200);
    }

    el.sendKeys(Keys.DOWN);
    el.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
```

Answer (score 0):

This may also happen because of the form design. For example, data masking/validation implementation may be buggy, which could cause this. Please evaluate the JavaScript around this input.

Sample https://github.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask/issues/505